# Converting long value to unichar* in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, long-integer, unichar

I'm storing large unicode characters (`0x10000`+) as `long` types which eventually need to be converted to `NSStrings`. Smaller unicode characters can be created as a `unichar`, and an `NSString` can be created using

```
[NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)characters length:(NSUInteger)length]
```

So, I imagine the best way to get an `NSString` from the unicode long value would be to first get a `unichar*` from the `long` value. Any idea on how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you are storing the values as `long`s? For Unicode storage you only need to store the values as `UInt32`, which would then make it easy to interpret the data as `UTF-32` by doing something like this:

```
int numberOfChars = 3;
UInt32* yourStringBuffer = malloc(sizeof(UInt32) * numberOfChars);
yourStringBuffer[0] = 0x2F8DB; //杞
yourStringBuffer[1] = 0x2318;  //⌘
yourStringBuffer[2] = 0x263A;  //☺

NSData* stringData = [NSData dataWithBytes:yourStringBuffer length:sizeof(UInt32) * numberOfChars];

//set the encoding according to the current byte order
NSStringEncoding encoding;
if(CFByteOrderGetCurrent() == CFByteOrderBigEndian)
    encoding = NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding;
else
    encoding = NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding;

NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:encoding];

free(yourStringBuffer);

NSLog(@"%@",string);

//output: 杞⌘☺
```